# Error- Controller Api Rest Spring JPA Maven(Update, Delete and Find)

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa

I have a problem when  I try to make requests only works for me post.The others it says that it does them on spring console but in the request it gives internal error 500.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")

public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private BoToDto boToDto;
    @Autowired
    private DtoToBo dtoToBo;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> createUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        try {
            UserBo userBo = dtoToBo.userDtoToBo(userDto);
            User savedUser = userService.save(userBo);
            UserDto savedUserDto = boToDto.userBoToDto(savedUser);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedUserDto);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getUserById(@PathVariable int id) {
        try {
            Optional<UserBo> userBoOptional = userService.findById(id);
            if (userBoOptional.isPresent()) {
                UserBo userBo = userBoOptional.get();
                UserDto userDto = boToDto.userBoToDto(userBo);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(userDto);
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            }
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> updateUser(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        try {
            UserBo userBo = dtoToBo.userDtoToBo(userDto);
            userBo.setId(id); // Asignar el ID del path al objeto UserBo
            User updatedUser = userService.update(userBo);
            UserDto updatedUserDto = boToDto.userBoToDto(updatedUser);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedUserDto);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

     @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
       public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable int id) {
           try {
               userService.delete(id);
               return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
           } catch (ServiceException e) {
               return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
           }
       }
     
    @GetMapping("/all")
       public ResponseEntity<List<UserDto>> getUsers() {
           try {
               List<UserBo> usersBO = userService.findAll();
               List<UserDto> usersDTO = usersBO.stream()
                       .map(boToDto::userBoToDto)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
               return ResponseEntity.ok(usersDTO);
           } catch (ServiceException e) {
               return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
           }
       }
}
```

Service Impl

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityToBo entityToBO;

    @Autowired
    private BoToEntity boToEntity;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    
    public UserServiceImpl(UserDao userDao, EntityToBo entitiToBo,BoToEntity boToEntity) {
        this.userDao=userDao;
        this.entityToBO=entitiToBo;
        this.boToEntity=boToEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public User save(UserBo userBo) throws ServiceException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            User user = userDao.save(boToEntity.userBoToEntity(userBo));
            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException("Error al guardar un nuevo usuario", e);
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public User update(UserBo userBO) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return userDao.save(boToEntity.userBoToEntity(userBO));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException("Error al actualizar el usuario", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            userDao.delete(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException("Error al eliminar el usuario", e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<UserBo> findAll() throws ServiceException {
        try {
            List<User> usersList = userDao.findAll();
            List<UserBo> usersBoList = new ArrayList<>();
            usersList.forEach((user) -> usersBoList.add(entityToBO.userToBO(user)));
            return usersBoList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException("Error al mostrar todos los usuarios", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<UserBo> findById(int id) throws ServiceException{
            

        try {
            UserBo userBo = entityToBO.userToBO(userDao.findById(id));
            return Optional.of(userBo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new ServiceException("Error al mostrar todos los usuarios", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UserBo findByNick(String nick) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            UserBo userBo = entityToBO.userToBO(userDao.findByNick(nick));
            return userBo;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException("Error al buscar un usuario por nick", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserBo> findByState(UserState state) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            List<User> usersList = userDao.findByState(state);
            List<UserBo> usersBoList = new ArrayList<>();
            usersList.forEach((user) -> usersBoList.add(entityToBO.userToBO(user)));
            return usersBoList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException("Error al buscar un usuario por estado", e);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Dao

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() throws DaoException {
        try {
            return userRepository.findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DaoException("Error al obtener todos los usuarios", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findById(int id) throws DaoException {
        try {
            return userRepository.findById(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DaoException("Error al buscar el usuario por id", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User findByNick(String nick) throws DaoException {
        try {
            return userRepository.findByNick(nick);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DaoException("Error al buscar el usuario por nick", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findByState(Enum userState) throws DaoException {
        try {

            return  userRepository.findByState(userState);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DaoException("Error al buscar el usuario por estado", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) throws DaoException {
        try {
            return userRepository.save(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DaoException("Error al guardar el usuario", e);
        }
    }

    

    @Override
    public void delete(int user_id) throws DaoException {
        try {
            userRepository.deleteById(user_id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DaoException("Error al eliminar el usuario", e);
        }
    }
}
```

JPA Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findByNick(String nick);

    List<User> findByState(Enum userState);

}
```

If I put the transactional annotation it gives me an error, I have looked and those are only needed when the database has to be modified, for example in search it would not be necessary, I have no idea why the create makes me and the others give me an internal error but there is no error in spring as it finds it well but does not show it in the request.

Example

FindAll:

Spring console - Hibernate: select u1_0.user_id,u1_0.user_avatar,u1_0.user_email,u1_0.user_nick,u1_0.user_password,u1_0.user_state from users u1_0

Postman 500Internal Server Error

Example Update:

Spring console

Hibernate: select u1_0.user_id,u1_0.user_avatar,u1_0.user_email,u1_0.user_nick,u1_0.user_password,u1_0.user_state from users u1_0 where u1_0.user_id=?

Postman 500Internal Server Error

Example delete Spring console Hibernate: select u1_0.user_id,u1_0.user_avatar,u1_0.user_email,u1_0.user_nick,u1_0.user_password,u1_0.user_state from users u1_0 where u1_0.user_id=?

Postman 500Internal Server Error

Comment: Log the exception in your catch block. No one can help without that